# How to fix "Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted." error in django

Tags: python, django, csrf, django-csrf, csrf-token

I'm getting this common error as in the title. I'm doing a project in Django in a virtual environment folder.

setting.py:

```py
        MIDDLEWARE = [
            'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
            'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
            'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
            'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
            'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
            'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
            'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
        ]
```

index.html:

```html
        {% load static %}
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>

        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Instapic</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/Login-Form-Clean.css' %}">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/styles.css' %}">
        </head>

        <body>
            <div class="login-clean">
                <form method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}

                    <h2 class="sr-only">Login Form</h2>
                    <div class="illustration">
                            <div style="display: none" id="errors" class="well form-error-message"></div>
                            <img src="{% static 'assets/img/logo.jpg' %}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" id="username" type="text" name="username" required="" placeholder="Username" maxlength="20" minlength="4">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" id="email" type="email" name="email" required="" placeholder="Email" maxlength="100" minlength="6">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" id="password" type="password" name="password" required="" placeholder="Password" maxlength="20" minlength="6">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="go" type="submit">Create Account</button>
                    </div><a href="#" class="forgot">Already got an account? Login here ...</a></form>
            </div>
            <script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
            <script src="{% static 'assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
            <script src={% static "assets/js/django-ajax.js" %}></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#go').click(function() {
                $.post("ajax-sign-up",
            {
                username: $("#username").val(),
                email: $("#email").val(),
                password: $("#password").val()
            },
            function(data, status){
            if (JSON.parse(data).Status == 'Success') {
                window.location = '/';
            } else {
                $('#errors').html("<span>" + JSON.parse(data).Message + "</span>")
                $('#errors').css('display', 'block')
            }
            });
                return false;
                })
        })
            </script>
        </body>

        </html>
```

I added `{% csrf_token %}` in my html file trying fix this - didn't work. I've found online this tag example:

`<input type="hidden" id="csrf_token" value='{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>`.

Unfortunately I don't know how to use it in order to fix my error.
Thanks for help

Comment: This happens when? when clicking on #go button? Did you read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/#ajax)

Comment: It would probably be easier if instead of passing the fields individually in your ajax post request you just get the form data (which would include the csrftoken). Or you follow the instructions in the link I gave in my previous comment.

Comment: i did not get it

Answer (score 3):

I guess, instead of post a form you are posting values.
You need to add *csrfmiddlewaretoken* key while execute $.post() statement.

This is **not Tested**  but it may be fix your problem

```
  csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value
```

or

```
 csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
```

add this line in HTML file by updating

```
$.post("ajax-sign-up",
    {
        username: $("#username").val(),
        email: $("#email").val(),
        password: $("#password"),
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
    },
```

updated code is :

```
    {% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Instapic</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/Login-Form-Clean.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/styles.css' %}">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="login-clean">
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}

            <h2 class="sr-only">Login Form</h2>
            <div class="illustration">
                    <div style="display: none" id="errors" class="well form-error-message"></div>
                    <img src="{% static 'assets/img/logo.jpg' %}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="username" type="text" name="username" required="" placeholder="Username" maxlength="20" minlength="4">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="email" type="email" name="email" required="" placeholder="Email" maxlength="100" minlength="6">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="password" type="password" name="password" required="" placeholder="Password" maxlength="20" minlength="6">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="go" type="submit">Create Account</button>
            </div><a href="#" class="forgot">Already got an account? Login here ...</a></form>
    </div>
    <script src="{% static 'assets/js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src={% static "assets/js/django-ajax.js" %}></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#go').click(function() {
        $.post("ajax-sign-up",
    {
        username: $("#username").val(),
        email: $("#email").val(),
        password: $("#password").val(),
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
    },
    function(data, status){
    if (JSON.parse(data).Status == 'Success') {
        window.location = '/';
    } else {
        $('#errors').html("<span>" + JSON.parse(data).Message + "</span>")
        $('#errors').css('display', 'block')
    }
    });
        return false;
        })
})
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: where should i add this? settings.py?

Comment: No in your HTML file. I update the code you can check it.

Comment: Try with @dirkgroten solution, its better solution in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just posting the contents of a HTML form with id `signup-form` (add that to the `<form>`), and your form has the `{% csrf_token %}`, then you can do that in ajax using:

```
$.post("ajax-sign-up", $("#signup-form").serialize(), function(data, status){...})
```

Comment: Look at your own HTML template, you already wrote `$.post("ajax-sign-up")...` yourself! I'm only suggesting to submit all the form fields instead of the 3 you wrote explicitly.

Comment: see the answer of @somil below, where it's spelled out for you. But please take your time and read the link until you understand it completely.